# Install Ruby 1.9.3 or 1.9.2 for Rails Apps

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm installing a new server for run Rails apps, I already have 1 app that I want to deploy, but it is on Ruby 1.9.2.

Which version of Ruby do you recommend me to install on the server, Ruby 1.9.3 (now the stable) or Ruby 1.9.2 ?

Comment: Whichever one you've tested it with (and it works). If you've tested it on both, IMO use the latest. Better yet, install both so you can roll back in an emergency.

Comment: Yep, that's 1.9.2, but... the stable is now the 1.9.3 no?

Comment: It doesn't matter what is called stable, what matters is what's known to work with your app.

Comment: @GoodEnough I heard it's pissed at 1.9.3; you never know when a release like that might just snap.

Comment: @DaveNewton "I heard it's pissed at 1.9.3" what does that even mean? Standard English is far more helpful than slang on a site that is read by those who are native and non-native speakers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using ruby 1.9.3 as the stable version comes with a patch for `require` which [should increase](http://www.rubyinside.com/ruby-1-9-3-faster-loading-times-require-4927.html) the speed of your rails app, but as always: `benchmark` is not your enemy!

Also AFAIK any ruby code written for ruby 1.9.2 should work just fine on 1.9.3, but not vice versa.So it should be save to move your app to 1.9.3.

Comment: Yes, that's the main gain you will get. I haven't benchmarked rails response rate on 1.9.3, but that's easy to do :).

Answer (score 3):

I would in any way suggest you use [RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/) since you may end up having to deploy another app too. And being able to switch rubies around is always nice.

Once RVM is up you can simply try it on 1.9.3 and 1.9.2 and use the latest that is working.

Comment: Thanks, I already consider to use RVM, but I want to install (this time) only a version of Ruby, remember this will be a production server

Comment: That's why I suggested RVM. Unless you have one production server per app RVM comes in really handy whenever you have a newer app to deploy side by side an older thing..

Comment: And RVM also makes it pretty simple to install Ruby .. even if you only install one Ruby

Comment: but you have to deal with path configurations and that stuff, I like RVM in dev environment but definitely it's not what I want in production. but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try your app on 1.9.3 and if it works then use that, otherwise consider if porting it to 1.9.3 is worth the time. There shouldn't be any issues but you should make sure.